# Multiple KeyEvents Occuring with KeyAdapter when entering only one character

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, keylistener

Adding a `KeyListener` class to a `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text` class.
When I enter `'a'`, I get multiple keyEvents.  I'm only expecting one keyEvent. 
Why is that.

```
text.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        super.keyReleased(keyEvent);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "keyEvent-->" + "\n" +  
                            "character :" + keyEvent.character + "\n" + 
                            "code      :" + keyEvent.keyCode + "\n" +
                            "location  :" + keyEvent.keyLocation + "\n" +
                            "stateMask :" + keyEvent.stateMask + "\n" +
                            "time      :" + keyEvent.time + "\n" +
                            "hashCode  :" + keyEvent.hashCode() + "\n" +
                            "data      :" + keyEvent.data + "\n" +
                            "doit      :" + keyEvent.doit + "\n");
    }
});
```

Output (after pressing "a" in the keyboard once):

```
keyReleased
INFO: keyEvent-->
character :a
code      :97
location  :0
stateMask :0
time      :15626510
hashCode  :692735
data      :null
doit      :true

keyReleased
INFO: keyEvent-->
character :a
code      :97
location  :0
stateMask :0
time      :15626510
hashCode  :32967617
data      :null
doit      :true

keyReleased
INFO: keyEvent-->
character :a
code      :97
location  :0
stateMask :0
time      :15626510
hashCode  :2412752
data      :null
doit      :true

keyReleased
INFO: keyEvent-->
character :a
code      :97
location  :0
stateMask :0
time      :15626510
hashCode  :17374804
data      :null
doit      :true

keyReleased
INFO: keyEvent-->
character :a
code      :97
location  :0
stateMask :0
time      :15626510
hashCode  :27668426
data      :null
doit      :true

keyReleased
INFO: keyEvent-->
character :a
code      :97
location  :0
stateMask :0
time      :15626510
hashCode  :25933099
data      :null
doit      :true
```

Comment: Can you try to reproduce this in an isolated context? Then it's easier to determine. (like make an easily compilable example)

First thing that comes to mind: You have added multiple KeyAdapters over the lifetime of the Component - try checking by seeing what `getKeyListeners().length` returns.

Comment: It turned out to be multiple issues. The method getKeyListeners().length showed that I had multiple KeyAdapter Listeners.  Also,the TextCellEditor class from which the Text widget came from also had a KeyUp listener itself.  Thanks for the help Danyel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have added multiple KeyAdapters over the lifetime of that component - try checking by seeing what `getKeyListeners().length` returns.